# Radio Button inside Foreach Loop -PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

How can I retain the selected radio button checked inside a foreach loop? Im developing a web application that checks first whether the selected service is available or not.

Here is my current code in foreach loop:

```
<h4>-- Touch Therapies --</h4>
    <?php
    $contents = get_service_touch(); //get_service_touch() = SELECT query to get touch therapies
    foreach($contents as $content) {
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="content_id" value="<?php echo $content['content_id']; ?>"
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['content_id'])){
        echo 'checked = "checked"';
    }
    ?>> 

    <?php echo nl2br($content['content']);?>
    <font color="red"><b>P<?php echo nl2br($content['price']);?></b></font><br>
    <?php   
    } //endforeach;
    ?>
```

However even if I select different service, when I click 'Check Availability' //(submit button) it always checks the last radio button.

Picture of foreach output: http://oi61.tinypic.com/rrnujd.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If content_id is in the POST then the checked attribute will be added to all inputs. I think you need to add an equality to your conditional.

```
if (isset($_POST['content_id']) && $_POST['content_id'] === $content['content_id']) {
     // echo checked
}
```